# Cast Chars To Int in Template Function

Tags: c++, templates, casting

I have a C++ template function which prints numbers.

It works fine for everything, except when I'm working with data of type `char`.

I'd like `char` to be printed as `int`, but if I cast this explicitly in the template function, then I will lose precision on my `float` types.

I'd like to be able to say:

```
template<class T> bob(T a){
  cout<<if_char_make_int(a)<<endl;
}
```

But I'm not sure how to do this, or if it is possible.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class T> void bob(T a){
    std::cout
      << typename boost::mpl::if_<boost::is_same<char, T>, int, T>::type(a)
      << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
template<class T> void bob(T a){
  cout<< a <<endl;
}

template<> void bob(char a){
  cout<< static_cast<int>(a) <<endl;
}
```

For more please read here http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/ (Template specialization)

Hope it helps

Comment: Besides a template specialization, you could also use an overload. I.e. just remove the `template<>`.

Comment: This seems an elegant solution, though, if the function is complex enough, the specialization results in large chunks of duplicated code... unless this particular function is then abstracted and specialized, which begins to seem inelegant. Mankarse provides a solution which seems to be more in the spirit of what I was looking for, but thank you for your otherwise excellent answer and for the helpful link - I appreciate that thoroughness.