# template function with pqxx results

Tags: c++, postgresql, templates

This is on os x yosemite with clang from xcode 7.2 in clion.

I'm iterating through a query from a postgresql db and adding the result to a json object.

```
for (pqxx::result::const_iterator c = R.begin(); c != R.end(); ++c) {
    participants["participants"] += { \
        {"id", c[0].as<std::string>()},
        {"location", c[1].as<std::string>()},
        {"racename", c[2].as<std::string>()},
        {"racestart_at", c[3].as<std::string>()},
        {"ended_at", static_cast<bool>(c[9].size()) ? c[9].as<std::string>() : ""},
        {"racetime", static_cast<bool>(c[10].size()) ? c[10].as<std::string>() : ""}
    };
}
```

Some of the columns have null values so I test for that casting to bool in a ternary operator and either return the result or an empty string. To make it a bit cleaner I tried to add a template function with the example from http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/templated_functions.html and had this:

```
template <class T>
std::string column_content(T a) {
    return static_cast<bool>(a.size()) ? a.as<std::string>() : "";
}
```

When I try to compile the program I get the error:

```
Database.cpp:9:44: error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'as' as a dependent template name
return static_cast<bool>(a.size()) ? a.as<std::string>() : "";
                                       ^
                                       template
```

I looked at [Cast Chars To Int in Template Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764295/cast-chars-to-int-in-template-function) and http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/ and other suggestions from google but it looks like I'm using the wrong syntax but I can't spot it.

If I could use a template function adding to json could then look like

```
{"start_at", column_content(c[8])}
```

regards
Claus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to a function for the time being. The type passed is pqxx::result::field as per http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/2.6.9/html/Reference/a00259.html#2a9d36599b217ebfde2cac4633856ac0.

```
std::string column_content(pqxx::result::field a) {
    if (static_cast<bool>(a.size())) {
        return a.as<std::string>();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```